# Auto update flutter query results in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am familiar with flutter basics and I know about stream builders. However how do I update my query results when it detects a change.
**Here is the code I would like to auto update when there is a change to the document**

```
 void initState() {
    getUsers();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUsers() async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;
    final QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await userRef.where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).get();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      name = doc["firstName"];
      children = doc["children"].toString();
      print(doc["children"].toString());
    });
  }
```

**This code works great, however when I change the number of children for instance, unless I restart the app, which of course, the user can not do**
**Here is an image of my firestore collection**
[Image of firestore collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4GGN.png)
As you can see, this query searches the entire collection for a document with the same uid as the current users uid. This is how I retrieve data specific to a user, like first and last name and children. I have a functionality that allows the user to add children, however, the number of children stays the same until I restart the app. How can I make the results auto update after then number of children changes.
Thanks!

Comment: What about using a `StreamBuilder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `get()` means that your application [reads the documents from the database once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), and then stops caring.

If you want to [get realtime updates from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) if the underlying data changes, you'll need to use the [`snapshots` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html), which gives you a `Stream` of updates.

To show that stream of updates in the UI, you'd use a `StreamBuilder` as shown in the FlutterFire documentation on [realtime changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes).

Comment: I dont see flutter or dart in any of the tabs in the links you gave me, should I use Java/Android as documentation in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: If you didn't see Flutter, you might not have clicked the last two links I gave. ;-)
Flutter code samples are not currently shown in the Firebase documentation itself, so you'll have to read about how it works in the Firebase documentation (the first two links), and then find the correct calls for Flutter in that documentation (the last two links I gave).