# Do I have to use a ListView in Streambuilder to get realtime updates in flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I recently asked a question on how to get realtime updates in flutter firestore. I received an answer that told me to use snapshots and redirected me to https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes.
However, every example I look at includes a list view, or some controversial change to the UI; a column, a listview, a container. All I wish to do is to update the value of a variable whenever a document changes. **Here is an image of my firestore database**
[My lovely database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqbs8.png)
In my code, I have a variable called `kChildren`, which stores the value of the `children` in a given document `xyz` in the collection `abc`. I want the value of the variable to update whenever the value of the `children` field updates in the document `xyz` in the collection `abc`. Then I will take the variable `kChildren` and concatenate it in a text widget. I don't want to change the UI at all, just change the value of the variable whenever the value of this one field in this one document in this one collection changes.
Thank you

**I have looked extensively in several questions and nearly all of them are outdated, several people mark my answer as already asked when in reality, the did a quick google search to a post 4 years ago**

Comment: Answer below. But if you're having a hard time making this work, I recommend showing what you tried with the information I showed/linked in my previous answer. Did you try to use the `snapshots` property yet for example? If you have a single `DocumentReference`, such a property also exists: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to use a `ListView`. As I said in my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68866176), if you want to show the value from the database in a UI, you'll typically want to use a `StreamBuilder` as shown in the docs I linked.

If you want to get the value in other code, or handle UI updates yourself, you'll still want to use the [`snapshots` member](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) to get the stream (as I said there too), but you can then call (for example) `listen()` on that stream to access the values.