# How to update a list automatically using Firestore Stream?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, provider

In my app, I am now using a "refresh function" to update a list in Provider. When the user swipe, I call Refreshlist in my provider and with NotifyListeners() it updates my UI just fine. (The UI is linked to the list _myEleves).
I am afraid that users might use this "refresh" button too many times making unnecessary calls and "reads" on firebase and so increasing artificially the number of reads so the costs of Firebase.

Here is the code :

```
 Future<void> refreshEleveList() async {
    final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> docInfo =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('familyAccounts')
            .doc(_accountEmail.toLowerCase())
            .get();
    _mesEleves = (docInfo['mesEleves'] as List<dynamic>)
        .map((data) => Eleve.fromMap(data))
        .toList();

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

I have been reading about STREAMS a lot, but I just can't get it right on how to start this stream, the listening to the changes on Firebase inside my PROVIDER file, so that changes will be made to "_myEleves" list.
What I want to do is that each time a change on firebase happens, it updates my list "_myEleves". Is there a simple way to do this ?

My Provider covers the whole app (I use it in the MAIN file). I thought of adding a StreamProvider, but the thing is I don't want this stream to start until user is authentified etc... and userInfo is first downloaded.

Right now : when user logs in : it downloads from firebase all necessary info, _mesEleves being one of them (This is for a teacher). Whenever a new student joins the group, it modifies firebase and so it should stream down this info into "myEleves" list on the teacher account.

Anybody can help ?

Comment: *"What I want to do is that each time a change on firebase happens, it updates my list "_myEleves". Is there a simple way to do this ?"* - check [realtime-changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes)

Comment: I had looked into stream builder : but it seems it returns "widgets" no ? how can I update my list using this technique ?

Comment: check `Stream.map` and [this](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods) in general

Comment: I don't see a solution :('  It shouldn't be so hard to "connect" a list to a Firestore stream... each time the stream gets changed, the list gets updated...

Comment: "each time the stream gets changed, the list gets updated" - and this is not you are expecting?

Comment: oh yes this is what I want, but can't do ;)

Comment: you have the example code in the [link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) i posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243893/discussion-between-sylvainjack-and-pskink).

Comment: can you refer to the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68866176/15774176 is it helpful?